# Matlab: How to matrix calculation with cell matrix?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I need to calculation `R*S*R'`.
`R` is an ordinary matrix. 
But `S` is composed of values. The element of `S` is the value of `F(w)`, and is calculated by

```
[PressureSpecAuto,F] = periodogram(....);
S{i,j} = PressureSpecAuto;
```

which means each element is a set of data.

The problem is that, Matlab cannot multiply cell matrix with matrix, then How can I solve this problem?

Notice: The element of `S` should not be treated as an vector. It's just the value set of  function F(w).

UPDATE1:

[image]

[image]

Element in S(the value set of a function)

[image]

Essentially, element in `S` is a function's value, e.g. `f(x)`. When multiplying, it is still R(1,:)*S(:,1). That is, R(1,1) * S(1,1) + R(1,2) * S(2,1) ...

UPDATE2:

```
R:
1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Element in S( e.g. S(1,1) ):

```
2.11586339015690e-23
6548.06822760155
10933.4416318101
67974.4878764171
1640.90694018577
22254.1105594943
54583.8668300499
25426.8190829386
4646.70203854458
19224.2485418923
17292.0278726986
928.765041030392
14728.5614115324
113385.034815149
30274.0332077125
22697.8886043178
61916.4030808219
38648.2740539840
127.547928632502
24452.0499691112
12311.1687443994
6627.23433956309
11264.7956369618
7232.97125504007
4120.08127891675
1546.69594235781
22795.2322822644
627.572461904325
9237.43533412019
3433.67898348596
```

Comment: Try the `cell2mat` function (see MATLAB help page for details)

Comment: @hbaderts the content of each element is the value of a function i.e(results). So I'm afraid it cannot be converted into matrix.

Comment: It would be better if you printed the values in the command window and pasted those as text rather than pasting screen shots.

Comment: I'm getting a bit lost I'm afraid. I think your question contradicts itself. You first say that you want to calculate `R*S*R'` but in your last statement you say that you want to calculate `R(1,1) * S(1,1) + R(1,2) * S(2,1) ... ` What are you trying to do? In case of `R*S*R'`, the matrix dimensions will mismatch. It will be `26x1 2049x1 1x26`.

Comment: @kkuilla, you maybe mistake the element of the `S` as the `S` matrix itself. The `2049*1` is just in one cell of the matrix `S`. `S` is `6*6`.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't make any sense. I'm still struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve. Have you changed the requirements so that you want to calculate `R(1,1) * S(1,1) + R(1,2) * S(2,1) ... ` now where R(:,1) is `26x1` and `S(1,1)'` is `1x2049`?  If so, the resulting matrix is 26x2049. Will the end result be a matrix of size `26x2049x6`?

Comment: @kkuilla  For `R(26*6) * S (6*6)`, the end result is `26*6`, with each cell is 2049 long. For example, you may start with `R(1,1) * S(1,1)`. It is just `R(1,1) .* (2049*1)`. The data in S(1,1) stands for the value of a function, not a vector.

Comment: You are not trying to do a matrix multiplication then, are you? You are saying that you want to do a matrix multiplication but it is actually something different. Your question does not reflect what you **really** want to achieve, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a loop? Maybe this would work then...

Just use a loop and loop through the indices of `S` to extract each matrix. Then do the multiplication.

In essence:

```
for n=1:numel(S) 
    R*S{n}*R' 
end
```

or using [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) where `@(x)` is an anonymous function.

```
cellfun(@(x) R*x*R', S, 'UniformOutput',false)
```

Comment: R*S{n}*R' is not correct. The element of the `S` is not a matrix. Rather, it's just a set of value of a function proximation. Hence, I think I need R(i,j)* S(i,j).

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand. If you are doing `R(i,j)*S{i,j}*R(I,j)'`, why do you then need to do matrix multiplication? `R` and `S` would then be scalar. I think it would be good if you posted samples of `R` and `S`.

Comment: My fault. I just mean multiply like general matrix operation. A(1,:)*B(:,1). See my update.